Arcade Attribute calculation rule using ArcGIS Pro
I am using ArcGIS Pro.
I have the Arcade code below which is working to an extent. It is populating the field in the $feature with the "School_Name" from the "Append_New" feature class for the nearest point, but I want the extent to be at 1000m. After that it should return a null value.
var searchDist = 1000 
var schools = Intersects(FeatureSetByName($datastore, "Append_New", 
["School_Name"]), Buffer($feature, searchDist, "meters"))
var nearestSchoolls)
var min_dist = 1000

for (var f in schools) {
var schoolDist = Round(Distance(f, $feature, "meters"),2)
if(schoolDist < min_dist) {
nearestSchool = f.School_Name;
min_dist = schoolDist
}
}

if (min_dist >= 1000) {
return "null"
} else {
return nearestSchool
}


What is the issue with the code as written?  Are you saying the code works as expected when the nearest point is < 1000m but not > 1000m?  If so, what are you getting for results when the nearest point is > 1000m?

Yes, exactly that. I am getting the nearest point regardless of if it is <1000m or >1000m

There were a couple of errors in your code (an errant parenthesis and a misspelled variable name). I've also added a check to see if there are any schools in the initial buffer before checking distances.
This code hasn't been checked, but it should work.
var searchDist = 1000;
var schools = Intersects(
  FeatureSetByName($datastore, "Append_New", ["School_Name"]),
  Buffer($feature, searchDist, "meters")
);
if (Count(schools) == 0) return null;

var nearestSchool;
var min_dist = 1000;

for (var f in schools) {
  var schoolDist = Round(Distance(f, $feature, "meters"), 2);
  if (schoolDist < min_dist) {
    nearestSchool = f.School_Name;
    min_dist = schoolDist;
  }
}
return nearestSchool;


The errors arent in the code, i must have copied it in funny. Sorry.
So i added the Count function to check if the schools variable is 0 and return null but its still not working as i would like it.
Its almost as if ArcPro is disregarding the buffer function. Essentially it should be just capturing what is the nearest point in the 1km buffer. Instead it is just picking out what is the nearest point from any distance.

I have tested this using my data in a popup and I'm getting the expected results. If I click a feature that is farther than 1000 meters, it returns null.

Yes, i tested in a pop up on ArcGIS online and it worked as expected but in a calculation attribute rule in ArcGIS Pro, it does not. I cannot figure out why. Projection possibly?

Yes, that's what I suspect

The dataset and map are in WGS84. Would it need to be Web Mercator?

If they are in the same coordinate system, there should be no issues, so I can't be sure why your code is failing
